# Will organize/is organising/ is going to organize/has organized

Tags: grammar

Which of the following verb forms are correct? The following are short notices. Can I use the following tenses interchangeably in an exam.

1 - This is to inform all the students that our school **has organized/is organising/will organise/is going to organise** a dance programme from 15 February, 2021 to 18 February 2021.

2- This is to inform all the students that our school **is going to celebrate/will celebrate/is celebrating** Mahatma Gandhi's birthday at the school ground on 2nd october this year.

Comment: They have slightly different meanings, but all are grammatical. I'm not going to explain every meaning, but saying someone "has organised" something means something different to saying they "will organise".

Answer (score 0):

I will generally and briefly explain the meanings of tenses mentioned,

has organized - **very** generally, something that already happened in the past. This is true for this particular event, so do not take it as a rule. Furthermore, you cannot say when it did happen while you use this tense.

is organizing - the action of the school organizing an event happens now (or is 100% decided to happen in the near future)

is going to / will organize - will happen in the future. In very basic English, you can say the two are the same. In a little bit more advanced English, be going to expresses something that is planned, and will something that has just been decided or is a conjecture about the remote future.

Comment: You may wish to look at the "tense table" answer in this post: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-an

Comment: Note that the _event_ may be in the future even when the organisation was in the past, it just means that the organisation is complete ready for the event to take place. The other two phrases indicate different degrees of preparedness: 'is organising' indicates that the work is ongoing but not complete and 'will organise' means that the intention is there but no organisational work has been done yet.

Answer (score 0):

All of the sentences you provided are fine. Any one of them would be fine to use.

There is a subtle distinction between whether a task was completed in the past or whether the task will be completed in the future.

- Sarah ***has arranged*** for us to meet with the engineering team next week. Sarah has already contacted everyone, and no further planning is required.
- Sarah ***will arrange*** for us to meet with the engineering team next week. She has not yet made any phone calls, or sent anYemails. However, Sarah will schedule everything by the end of the week.

The question is, has the work been completed yet, or is there still more work to do?

- John's mother **is baking** a cake for his birthday. She is currently  in the kitchen mixing flour sugar, and water in a large steel bowl. She is not swimming at the community recreation center. A person cannot simultaneously swim and bake a cake at the same time.
- John's mother ***has baked*** a cake for his birthday. I hope that the cake does not go rancid. It will not be John's birthday for another four days.
- John's mother ***will*** bake a cake for his birthday. She is currently on her way to the store to purchase the ingredients. She has not baked the cake yet, but she plans to make it on Thursday.

Comment: Hello, Samuel. If only English were so simple. 'John's mother is baking a cake for his birthday', for instance, is often used to mean 'John's mother is going to bake a cake for his birthday'.